# Redirecting bad url links from external sites with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two inbound links that land on 404 pages because the links are squiffy. I have tried 301'ing these links as normal but without success, I believe because of the characters used from this external URL.

```
Column<u>Radiators.html
```

is the page suggested on this external site and

```
Column_Radiators.html
```

is the actual page.

also

```
Bath%3Cu%3EFiller.html
```

on the external site and

```
Bath_Filler.html
```

on our actual website.

How can I succesfully redirect these pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add these lines in your .htaccess

```
redirect 301 /Column<u>Radiators.html /index.html
redirect 301 /Bath<u>Filler.html /index.html
```

Note: I use index.html as the default redirection but you can use a custom 404.

Comment: Thank you that works, having revisited this I am unsure as to why I appeared to not having it working in the first place. As I am certain that I did this with the Column_Radiators.html page and saw no positive results but it now works (obviously I'm going a little crazy!)